# Centralized configuration for microservices and fat clients

Tags: microservices, apache-zookeeper, consul, configuration-management, etcd

We're looking into how we could manage the configuration of several microservices (10 - 15 services) and fat client applications which are installed in equipment (several hundreds). The applications are being developed in Java (for what it's worth). The equipment doesn't always have a working connection to the network, so the configuration must also be cached locally.

We have been looking in to Spring Cloud Config and services such as Consul, Zookeeper and Etcd. We particularly like Consul as it comes with a lot of functionality out-of-the-box, not in the latest a user interface.

What we are still struggling with is how we should setup such a tool especially for the equipment configuration. We have four different types of equipment which can be running slightly different versions of their respective applications. These applications share some configuration settings, whereas other settings are specific to a version, an equipment type or even a single equipment.

It seems pretty easy to store the configuration for one version of a single type in a tool like Consul, but how could we structure the settings in Consul for the environment we have in such a way that it is still clear and understandable for service engineers who shouldn't be too familiar with all the intricacies of the application? Is Consul actually the right tool for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain if you want to simplify your configuration management that you can reuse anytime.

You might want to check out some popular Key-Value Management software such as Hashicorp Vault, AWS Secret Manager, Bitnami Sealed Secrets, and others.

Cheers!

Comment: Vault etc. are secrets managers and not kv-stores perse. The kv-store associated with Vault would be Hashicorp's Consul. Indeed we are looking into simplifying things a bit. We have performed some preliminary tests and it seems possible to get the hierarchical behavior we want with a small change in the spring-consul client. Other things we should see if we can do that in the kv-store or with a different setup in our software.